# Scheme car and cdr recursion

Tags: recursion, scheme, cons, cdr

Can someone explain to me how the recursion works in the following function? Specifically, I am interested in what happens when the function reaches its base case. Also, why is a named let used in this code? (I am not familiar with named lets)

```
(define (unzip list-of-pairs)
  (if (null? list-of-pairs)
   (cons '() '())
   (let ((unzipped (unzip (cdr list-of-pairs))))
         (cons (cons (car (car list-of-pairs)) (car unzipped))
               (cons (cdr (car list-of-pairs)) (cdr unzipped))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure shown doesn't have anything special about it, you're just iterating over a list of this form:

```
'((1 . 2) (3 . 4) (5 . 6))
```

The only "weird" part is that the output is building *two* lists instead of the usual single list. As you know, when we're building a single list as output the base case is this:

```
(if (null? lst) '() ...)
```

But here, given that we're simultaneously building two lists, the base case looks like this:

```
(if (null? lst) (cons '() '()) ...)
```

The code in the question is not using a [named `let`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29), it's just a plain old garden-variety `let`, there's nothing special about it. It's useful because we want to call the recursion only once, given that we need to obtain two values from the recursive call.

If we don't mind being inefficient, the procedure can be written without using `let`, at the cost of calling the recursion two times at each step:

```
(define (unzip list-of-pairs)
  (if (null? list-of-pairs)
      (cons '() '())
      (cons (cons (car (car list-of-pairs))
                  (car (unzip (cdr list-of-pairs))))
            (cons (cdr (car list-of-pairs))
                  (cdr (unzip (cdr list-of-pairs)))))))
```

Of course, the advantage of using `let` is that it avoids the double recursive call.

Comment: There is something fishy about the implementation too. Eg. try `(unzip '((a b c) (1 2 3))) ; ==> ((a 1) (b c) (2 3))`

Comment: @Sylwester that input would be wrong for the procedure, it expects a list of _pairs_, ex.: `'((1 . 2) (3 . 4) (5 . 6))`

Comment: So it's not (un)zip, but a recursive version of `(cons (map car lst) (map cdr lst))`.  Got it :)